# WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for version 114

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, dependencies, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-devtools-protocol

WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for . You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.6.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.

Chrome version: 114
Selenium version: 4.6
Chromedriver version: 114

still nothing works?

I tried adding dependencies but nothing works.Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved for me with below tools/dependencies.

Chrome version 114.0.5735
selenium-java 4.1.3
selenium-devtools-v113 -  4.9.1
Added dependencies for selenium-java & selenium-devtools-v113  in POM.xml